# ArcGIS SQL Server - Using Windows Authentication

Tags: arcgis-server, sql-server, authentication

I want to use a domain level service account to manage my database connections.  This account is added as a Windows authenticated account in SQL Server 2012 as a sysadmin.  If I try to use this account as the Database Administrator in the Create Enterprise Geodatabase tool with the Database Authentication option I get a bad user login error, but only if I am logged into my workstation as my regular account.  If I log into my workstation as the service account and use Database Authentication and supply the domain account credentials again it works.

Shouldn't this work independently of who is logged into the workstation?  Is there a way to specify a Windows account when using Database Authentication, beyond using "domain\username"?

Comment: Windows Authentication is just that -- using what Windows provides.  How could such a function trust any other assertion of identity?  Have you tried to right-click "Run as Administrator..." in lieu of a full login?